# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect this html file to my Realtime Database in Firebase. My goal is to have a text box where a user enters their name and age and hits submit. This data is then uploaded to my database. For some reason, I continue to get the mentioned error. Here is the code for the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->
        <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

        <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

        <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

        <script>
            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyDNNyEXfTKKT2_zIplkvCdGc_By7MuXft4",
            authDomain: "website-68a74.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://website-68a74.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "website-68a74",
            storageBucket: "website-68a74.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "132124111779",
            appId: "1:132124111779:web:4e40136658453012d76016",
            measurementId: "G-61KJLELKZ9"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        function writeData()
        {
            firebase.database.ref("User").set
            ({
                name: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
                age: document.getElementById("ageField").value
            });
        }
        </script>
        <h1>User Database</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="nameField">
        <input type="text" placeholder="age" id="ageField">
        <button onclick="writeData()">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have looked over Firebase's documentation and have found no solutions. Any proposals would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to write:

```
firebase.database().ref("User")
```

Note the parenthesis after "database".  It's function call, not a property

Comment: Yes, this was one problem, but led me to find that I was actually missing a dependency. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution with the help of the upvoted answer. Yes I was to actually use firebase.database().ref("User"), but just doing so results in another error where firebase.database() is not a function. To fix this, one must also include another dependency. The new code is included below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->
        <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase.js"></script>

        <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

        <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

        <script>
            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyDNNyEXfTKKT2_zIplkvCdGc_By7MuXft4",
            authDomain: "website-68a74.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://website-68a74.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "website-68a74",
            storageBucket: "website-68a74.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "132124111779",
            appId: "1:132124111779:web:4e40136658453012d76016",
            measurementId: "G-61KJLELKZ9"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        function writeData()
        {
            firebase.database().ref("User").set
            ({
                name: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
                age: document.getElementById("ageField").value
            });
        }
        </script>
        <h1>User Database</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="nameField">
        <input type="text" placeholder="age" id="ageField">
        <button onclick="writeData()">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```